# Validation Form with PHP or Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have a form. column contents as follows.
fullname, email, mobile, and address

if the visitor fills out a field phone then allowed only enter numbers. and if the visitor fills out a field phone then allowed only enter email.

how to make the implementation of such a form.

Comment: and you tried something allready? or do we have to do your work???

Comment: My initial guess would be code

Comment: Something tells me you haven't even writen the form for this

Comment: Use RegExp .. we are not here to complete your home work. try urself, we'll help u to move on if u stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the visitor fills out a field phone then allowed only enter numbers. and if the visitor fills out a field phone then allowed only enter email.

Check this out

```
    function validateForm(){
    var x = document.getElementById('name');
    var email = document.getElementById('email');
    var num = document.getElementById('number');
    var size = document.getElementById('size');
    var filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
    var atpos=email.value.indexOf("@"); 
    var dotpos=email.value.lastIndexOf(".");

    if (x.value == null || x.value == "") {
    alert("Please Enter your name");
    x.focus();
    x.style.background = 'Yellow';
    return false;
    }
    if(!filter.test(email.value)){
    alert('Please provide a valid email address');
    email.focus();
    email.value="";
    return false;
    }
    if(num.value == null || num.value == ""){
    alert('Please enter your mobile number');
    num.focus();
    return false;
    }

    if(isNaN(num.value)){
    alert('Please enter a valid number');
    num.focus();
    num.style.background = 'Yellow';
    return false;
    }


}
```

Demo @: http://jsfiddle.net/e4E7D/2/